How to unlok the screen from the application in background?
I need to unlock screen of the application when I receive event to be able to access camera.  My application was sent to background because of home button press and screen was locked. My app already has keepScreenOn, but because home button was pressed, it is not active anymore and screen was locked.
I tried to use powerManager.newWakeLock in foreground service - I do receive SCREEN_OFF event when screen is locked, but nothing happens when I call acquire().
I also tried to startActivity with flags ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.BroughtToFront - it is bringing application from locked status, but when I open another app or get incoming call, the screen gets locked again.

Are you sure you really need to unlock the screen to access camera? Android apps can be shown on lock screen no problem and use camera in this situation. Maybe your problem is not unlocking the device (which I highly doubt is possible automatically if the device is locked by keyguard) but rather making sure it is relaunched on the lock screen when some event happens.
